# What to do with grapefruit seeds?

Tags: fruit, culinary-uses, citrus, seeds

I have several grapefruit trees and get tons of grapefruits almost year round. When I eat the grapefruits, which is fairly regular, I typically eat a good amount of the seeds with the fruit for nutrition, though I do get tired of them after a while.

Is there any recommendation as far as what to do with grapefruit seeds that might break the monotony of just eating them raw? Any way to prepare them or mix them into something... I've put them into smoothies which works fine, but I'm trying to see if there is anything more creative out there that I haven't considered.

Comment: You could try roasting them like pumpkin seeds: http://www.marthastewart.com/351200/roasted-pumpkin-seeds The worst that can happen is that you won't like the result.

Comment: I had thought about that - didn't sounds too appealing, but it wouldn't take long to find out if its good or not.

Comment: Hello jhawes. We have very strict guidelines on culinary uses questions (http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines), and many new users tend to break them because they are not aware of them. Your question fits them well. No matter if you knew about them or not, thank you for providing a good example that the policy can work, and that it is worth keeping the complicated distinction instead of summarily closing all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first reaction was to think that grapefruit seeds have cyanide, don't they? Nope, that's apples, apricots and peaches.

I did find an application you might find interesting: [Grapefruit Seed Extract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapefruit_seed_extract)

> Self-made pure GSE processed without solvents is prepared by grinding the grapefruit seed and juiceless pulp, then mixing with glycerin.

A few sites suggest that it's not quite that simple, but a [Google Search for "grapefruit seed extract homemade"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=grapefruit+seed+extract+homemade) will give you quite a bit of reading material.

If you try this, I hope you let us know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah the grapefruit seed extract is a pretty intensive... not that it isn't a solution, but I was looking more of something that could be a simple solution. From more searching I don't think there really is - it can be re-planted, put in a smoothie (little flavor to them), or as you suggested it can be made into an extract.

Comment: @jhawes Can you sprout grapefruit seeds, and for example, use them in salads?

Comment: great idea @ElmerCat - I hadn't even thought of that!